# Orthogonally cutting spheres

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

Prove that every sphere through the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax+r^2=0$, $z=0$ cuts orthogonally every sphere through the circle $x^2+z^2=r^2, y=0$.

I am studying sphere by myself, but while finding the equation of spheres from that two given circles, in both cases I am not getting $z^2$ & $y^2$ respectively in two equations, please help.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the meaning of the expression "cuts orthogonally". What do you mean by this? When two spheres intersect, you get a circle.

Comment: @Andrei: This means that at points that the two spheres intersect, their tangent planes are orthogonal (or, equivalently, that their normal vectors are orthogonal).

Comment: if the tangent planes of two spheres at the point of intersection are at right angles ,then it is said those two circles cut each other orthogonally I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sphere containing the first circle is of the form
$$x^2+(y-b)^2+z^2=b^2+r^2$$
for some real number $b$. Similarly, any sphere containing the second circle is of the form
$$(x-a)^2+y^2+(z-c)^2 = a^2+b^2-r^2$$
for some real number $c$. Adding the two equations gives us
$$2(x^2-ax+y^2-by+z^2-cz) = 0$$
whenever $(x,y,z)$ belongs to both spheres. But this equation tells us that the vectors $(x,y-b,z)$ and $(x-a,y,z-c)$ have dot product zero. This in turns tells us that the normal vectors to the respective spheres are orthogonal at such a point $(x,y,z)$, which is what you needed to show.